# How can I add dynamic field in Google Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-forms

Is there any feature  [Add New Field using jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-dynamic-form/) or  [Add fields using Javascript](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/examples/addfield.php) in Google forms?

I'm creating a questionnaire application using google apps script and questions and answers will be set from my admin panel (admin decide how many questions will be there). It would be perfect if there was a (+) next to the form to automatically load another text box underneath the form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I founded the perfect reason for this why it's unable to add dynamic fields with the Google Forms because Google Forms applications are totally bonded with the spread sheets

All the Forms having individual spreadsheets there.

So, it's impossible to generate dynamic fields in the Google forms because of strongly associated with the spreadsheet so.

This we can say the static relation between Google Forms and Spreadsheets.

Comment: At this time, submitting Google Forms responses to a Google spreadsheet is optional and it's possible to create or update Google Forms from spreadsheet data. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to build a new page that can submit to a Google spreadsheet using Using jQuery with JSON and Google Spreadsheets Data API

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Yes you can create/edit a form programmatically  by using the Forms Service [Class Form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form)

Note: At this time it's not possible to make changes to form / questions based on user input like making cascading dropdowns.

## Extended answer

The following are the specific methods to add each question type to a Google form.

```
Method                      Return type             Brief description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
addCheckboxItem()           CheckboxItem            Appends a new question item that allows the respondent to select one or more checkboxes, as well as an optional "other" field.
addDateItem()               DateItem                Appends a new question item that allows the respondent to indicate a date.
addDateTimeItem()           DateTimeItem            Appends a new question item that allows the respondent to indicate a date and time.
addDurationItem()           DurationItem            Appends a new question item that allows the respondent to indicate a length of time.
addGridItem()               GridItem                Appends a new question item, presented as a grid of columns and rows, that allows the respondent to select one choice per row from a sequence of radio buttons.
addListItem()               ListItem                Appends a new question item that allows the respondent to select one choice from a drop-down list.
addMultipleChoiceItem()     MultipleChoiceItem      Appends a new question item that allows the respondent to select one choice from a list of radio buttons or an optional "other" field.
addParagraphTextItem()      ParagraphTextItem       Appends a new question item that allows the respondent to enter a block of text.
addScaleItem()              ScaleItem               Appends a new question item that allows the respondent to choose one option from a numbered sequence of radio buttons.
addTextItem()               TextItem                Appends a new question item that allows the respondent to enter a single line of text.
addTimeItem()               TimeItem                Appends a new question item that allows the respondent to indicate a time of day.
```

## See also

- [Can I fill in TextItem by Google apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320670/can-i-fill-in-textitem-by-google-apps-script/20320727#20320727)