# Can I fill in TextItem by Google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I made a form with Google Form Builder, then I add a script for it.

I can run Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail() to the respondent's email address. but I cant fill it in the textbox to assist them. Can I do such thing with Google App Script?

Answer (score 6):

I think I found a solution to your problem. But I must admit it was not evident.
In apps scripts documentation you've got everything to create a [prefilled url](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#toPrefilledUrl()).
BUT for that you need to have a **ItemResponse** element and I didn't found any explaination to build one. The trick is when you've got an **item** you can get a **ItemResponse** from it if you get it as a defined type "**asTextItem()**".
Best way to understand it, is to watch the code below:

```
function getPreFilledItem(){
  var form = FormApp.openById("YOUR_FORM_ID"); 
  var items = form.getItems();
  var itemOfInterest;
  for(var i in items){
    if(items[i].getTitle()=="YOUR_QUESTION_TITLE"){
      itemOfInterest=items[i];
    }
  }
  Logger.log(
    form.createResponse().
    withItemResponse(itemOfInterest.asTextItem().createResponse("PREFILLED_TEXT")).
    toPrefilledUrl()
  );
}
```

Hoping this will help you,
Harold

Answer (score 2):

You can't dynamically modify Google Forms by attaching a script to the Form. See a [recent question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695489/google-forms-script-to-move-user-to-new-page-in-the-form) to get a better understanding.

Basically, you can only use Google Apps Script to create forms in an automated manner. You can't set values for the items as of yet (I certainly hope they add this in the future...).

You can also see the limitations for Forms by looking at the documentation ([TextItem, for example)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item).

Comment: Sigh, I've just been looking that ref again and again, and just pray for what you said is not true :(

Comment: Unfortunately the Forms service is a bit under-developed, in my opinion. Forms are what drive the work-flow at my office - the fact that there are severe limitations is kind of unfortunate. It is really unfortunate that we can't use GAS to auto-fill some elements of the form, like email address. That would prevent *so* many problems... Maybe they'll make Forms more accessible to Apps Script soon! We can only hope :P