# Possible to pre-assign user to google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am creating a Google Form dynamically, and emailing it, using Google Apps Script.

I have all the users info, and have figured out how to record the response. However, I would like to add that person's email to the row in the sheet.

It would be ideal if there was a way, since we already collected their email, to pass this email in the "background" to the form we send, and it is attached with there answer in the responses sheet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to rest until I got this worked out. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21284556/4305236) from almost three years ago really helped.

Not exactly what I was going for, still open if anyone knows how to actually pass info in the background to a sheet.

```
var items = formName.getItems();
var itemOfInterest;
for(var i in items){
  if(items[i].getTitle()=='QUESTION_TITLE'){
    itemOfInterest=items[i];
  }
}
var preFilledUrl =
    schedForm.createResponse().
withItemResponse(itemOfInterest.asTextItem().createResponse(email)).
toPrefilledUrl();
```

This prefills that question box, so also giving the user the ability to edit before they send. It'll work.