# Q: getDateCreated() for individual sheet, google apps

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a single spreadsheet that answers from an unlimited amount of dynamically created google forms go to, and each form means a new sheet(tab).

While I'm iterating through the sheets, doing what I need to do with the data, I want to clean up and delete any sheets over 3 weeks old to keep this from getting too crazy.

I have pretty much all the logic figured out, except I can't figure out how to get when that specific sheet was created.

There is the Drive Method getDateCreated() for files, but it will not work on sheets.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since your sheets are created from a form, there should be a timestamp created on the sheet. I would try using the timestamp to select the sheets to be deleted. As far as  I know, there is no date created for a sheet.

Comment: Well, there is a timestamp column, however that is added when form submitted submits. My challenge is cleaning up all the ones without responses

Comment: Could you delete the sheet if the timestamp is null?

Comment: I don't want to delete all the sheets immediately that haven't received response from connected form. However they are irrelevant after three weeks, so to keep it clean I need to delete them after a certain amount of time. If I  understand what you're suggesting, it won't work because deleting if timestamp was null would mean deleting all sheets that haven't received a response.

Comment: How and when do you create the sheet for the response?

Comment: Form is created dynamically, based on submission of [another form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfIPnhUPv_6VPhFsoc1PimJLrCuKztsW8-hOAlLrgsZoJuIyg/viewform) (an application to work with us).

If they pass all the requirements, it pulls dates from our calendar for upcoming interviews, creates a form for them to choose a time, & emails them that form.

The sheet is automatically created with & linked to the form, & the form is emailed to them.

This is for a non-skilled job, we get a ton of applicants through craigslist, etc, who drop off, this is to help filter all the mess.

Comment: When you create the sheet and link it to the form, add a date outside of where the form responses will be recorded and then use that as your delete criteria.

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar problem to what I needed in in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39940488/4305236), I wanted to pass the email of user. We don't need their email on here unless they complete the form, so I made a different workaround.
If, like I was initially looking for here, there was a way to pass a timestamp to sheet upon form creation, that would work.