# Dynamic field creation google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, purchase-order

Is it possible to add questions to a google form based on if the user wants to add a few more clusters of data?
i.e. a user is asked to enter information about the pets they have.  If they have one pet, a user enters information for one pet.  if the user wants to add another pet, they are prompted and asked if they want to add another pet.  The user then selects yes, and another few fields appear.
When the user is done adding pets, they say they are done, and move on.

I assume using a class form would allow me to add a text field, but is there an issue with how the information is pushed to the spreadsheet?

This example says that although you can add fields, you cannot capture the data into a spreadsheet since they are already formed.

[How can I add dynamic field in Google Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178175/how-can-i-add-dynamic-field-in-google-form)

Thanks

Comment: Generally google forms was designed to be easy to use.  If you're looking for more complex interactions I'd recommend that you roll your own with HtmlService.

Comment: Yes you can. See an older test formula https://forms.gle/62h4NXf7VshT6Y7R9

Comment: thanks @marikamitsos!  That is exactly the response I was looking for for my first step.  It's a little elusive being that one is not really looping but more like jumping sections if they don't need to add any more information.  How do you handle the depositing of the form data into a spreadsheet?  Do you capture each section into a different spreadsheet or do you just work with the dataset as a long row?

Comment: All in one spreadsheet.  I am away from the office at the moment. Will provide a full answer once back if you can wait a couple of days.

Comment: @marikamitsos I am doing it all in one spreadsheet also.  No problem and it's finally working!!!

Answer (score 1):

We were able to resolve this by using the native structure of google forms by adding a separate section for information gathered for the data row set.
At the end of the product section, if the user wishes to add another row of data, for us, it was another product, one adds a multiple choice question which prompts the user to either add another product, or to move to the final step (submit or adding shipping info or whatever).
If the user elects to add another product, it jumps to the next section, if not, it jumps to the ending section, in our case, procurement info.  The ability to jump from section to section is available through the selection menu on the three vertical dots next to the question.
The limitation is that the creator of the form must copy the repeated section the number of times a new product can be added.
Once this is complete, the script in the spreadsheet the form is linked to, iterates through the columns and plugs it into the document.

Comment: I see you already used the logic in the form I provided to you and gave your own answer. Good. You don't have to wait then.