# Dynamically appending input field in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I was making this form collecting information about team members of participant teams associated with a competition. The number of members in the team is not fixed. So, I want google form to load number of name fields equivalent to the number of members specified by the user. Is it possible to do it by using App Script or is there any pre-developed add-on which can be used for the same?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think your question got voted down because you don't give a clear example of what you're trying to do (what does your input look like, what do you want the output to look like), nor do you say anything about how you've tried to solve this problem. I came here because I have a similar question myself, so I'm going to upvote you and hope that someone provides an answer.

Comment: @itzy Actually I opted for developing a HTML form and then used JS for my requirement. However there is this one alternative with google form discussed here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66932256/dynamic-field-creation-google-forms